# view-model to entity binder

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, reflection, model-binding

I have a question that I don't know how to ask it. See; I have an entity like this:

```
public class Person{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

and also have a view-model with same properties as entity:

```
public class PersonModel{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

My question is: how can I create a auto convertor for reading properties from one of them, and create a new another one and write it properties from the first? see:

```
// DAL
public class Repository{
    public void Save(Person person){
        // saving a person entity
    }
}

// BLL
public class Service{
    public void CreatePerson(PersonModel model){
        var person = new Person{
            Id = model.Id,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };
        new Repository().Save(person);
    }
}
```

I have to repeat this code for converting all view-models to entities when I want to pass them from service to repository. I know about `explicit` and `implicit`, I don't want to use them. I mean I'm searching a way to auto binding them via reflection and generics. for example something like this:

```
public class Binder{
    public TOut Bind<TIn, TOut>(TIn inObject){ }
}
```

Has everybody any idea that where I should start or where can I find some resources to learning this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

#### AutoMapper - Best Way

Look at this. It's perfect for your problem:
[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Example:

```
public User Create(User obj) {
    var rep = UnitOfWork.Create<User>();
    var usr = Mapper.Map(obj, rep.Create());
    rep.Add(usr);

    return usr;
}
```

If you want to ignore some properties while mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, User>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.Ignore()) // Dont map the ID.
```

#### Reflection - Slow way

If you want to use reflection, then here is an example. But for the record. This is just a small sample how it *could* work. If it's a Generic Type, an array or something else, it doesn't work!

```
var modelProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(var prop in usr.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    var thisProp = modelProperties.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == prop.Name);
    if(thisProp != null) {
        var value = prop.GetValue(usr, null);
        thisProp.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to guide. but I want to learn it, not just use an external library. I download it, and look at its source, it's too hard for me understanding its code. I'm searching a simple begginer point to learning. Can you help me? or do you know any resource or starter point?

Comment: Okay, i added a simple and small example with reflection. But for the future: I would prefer the AutoMapper, because it's fast and mostly safe. The AutoMapper does the mapping in IL-Code -  i think - so it's not trivial to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extension Methods to copy the properties to another object:

```
public static class ConvertPersonToPersonModel
{
    public static PersonModel ConvertToPersonModel(this Person person)
    {
        PersonModel p= new PersonModel(); //assign the properties
        p.Id = person.Id; 
        p.FirstName = person.FirstName; 

        return p;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PersonModel> ConvertPeopleToPeopleModels(this List<Person> people)
    {
        List<PersonModel> ps= new List<PersonModel>();
        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            ps.Add(ConvertToPersonModel(person));
        }
        return ps.AsEnumerable<PersonModel>();
    }
}
```

The ConvertPersonToPersonModel() method will now show up on your Person object e.g.

```
Person p = new Person
p.ConvertToPersonModel();
```